# Calling parents by name

Tags: razor, knockout.js, viewmodel, partial

Is there a way/plugin to call `$parents["ExamViewModel"]` instead of `$parents[2]`?

That would be very helpful for shared views that may show in different parent views.

Comment: Hint: If you have such problems you have to probably rethink your concepts. It is a code smell to call parents directly. Always try to pass things from parents to children.

Comment: Agree, working to clear it out

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such thing.

You could create your own method using [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) as a cleaner way.

Something like:

```
function findParentOfType(parents, targetType) {
    for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
        if (parents[i] instanceof targetType) return parents[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
findParentOfType($parents, ExamViewModel)
```

Example:

```js
function Class1() {
 this.name = 'MyClass1';
}

function Class2() {
 this.name = 'MyClass2';
}

var parents = [new Class1(), new Class2()];

function findParentOfType(parents, targetType) {
    for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
        if (parents[i] instanceof targetType) return parents[i];
    }
    return null;
}

console.log(findParentOfType(parents, Class2).name);
```

Comment: Thanks!  for (var i = 0; i < parents.length -1; i++)

Comment: @user2769267 oops, fixed

Comment: getting error right side of instanceof is not an object , Any thought ?